# Batch file is not importing data into the datadbase

Tags: windows, batch-file, database

I'm trying to connect to orientdb, then restore values into the particular database, using this batch file:

```
 cd C:\All_Projects\orientdb-community-2.2.34\bin
 start console.bat , CONNECT PLOCAL:../databases/karthickTesting admin admin
IMPORT DATABASE C:\1MAASDB.gz -preserveClusterIDs=true
```

However, when I run it the import code doesn't work.

How do I run these multiple commands in a single `.bat` file?

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? Why are you running the console.bat? Does it accept parameters?

Comment: This will be hard to answer without knowing exactly what happens when you run it, and what is in console.bat.  Are these commands what it is that you want to save as the console.bat file, or arguments you want to pass to console.bat when you run it?

Comment: the console.bat to connect orientdb console, so why i am using here.

Comment: fixer1234 - when i am running this bat, the cmd takes only connect plocal, the import database command was ignored by cmd